# I need to know weather we would get the message again once it failed by the n service bus

Tags: nservicebus

like if there is a DivideByZzero exception so it requires a code fix and if the code gets fixed will it tries to resend the same message again

Comment: Why do you need to? If a message is retried enough times and still cannot be processed, it will get to the configured error queue, where you can inspect, fix the code, retry and eventually have it processed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Okay so once we have fixed the code, will it be in queue again to process the same message that failed because of the code bug. Now the code bug is solved will this will process again in any queue

Comment: The message will be in the error queue. You will still need to move it back to where it was before it gets processed. Using NSB you can do it in a few ways e.g. using ServicePulse but can also be done manually (the 'how' depends on the transport of choice)

Comment: @Hadi Eskandari, could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463253/does-an-nservicebus-error-mean-that-messages-are-not-processed-in-the-right-orde ? It is similar to this one.